# Sitecore 8.2 and Azure search indexes have different names

Tags: azure-search, paas

I have an inherited an instance of Sitecore 8 deployed to azure PaaS. Sitecore has been set up to use Azure search, however when I look in Sitecore the names of the indexes are slightly different from the index names in Azure.  It seems the developer used underscores in Sitecore in place of spaces however in Azure the underscores have been replaced with hyphens.  Does anyone know if this is standard behavior.  An example is below

```
sitecore index = search_web_index
azure index = search-web-index
```

Comment: Not sure if standard behavior but can verify this is the same for me. As a side note you will notice that field names are often different in azure search compared with solr as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Search only supports the following characters for index names (see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/naming-rules):

- Letters, numbers, dashes ("-")

Sitecore handles this internally and automatically converts underscores to dashes when initializing the `CloudSearchProviderIndex` used for Azure Search. So it's not something you need to think about at all, unless you query Azure Search directly.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option is to reject the name (I think this is the case for XConnect in 9), since this is due to an [Azure Search limitation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-index):

> The index name must be lower case, start with a letter or number, have no slashes or dots, and be less than 128 characters. After starting the index name with a letter or number, the rest of the name can include any letter, number and dashes, as long as the dashes are not consecutive.